# MongoDB $lookup on multiple documents results in an empty array

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 collections

1. Book - Has details about books
2. Library - Has details about Libraries
3. Book_Library - Each entry has a book id, library id and a unique id book id_library id.

I understand that this question has been asked before, but I cannot seem to find a solution that works for my case.

What I am attempting is to project a field from book and another from library which do not directly have a relationship but each have a relationship with book_library. And then count the number of genre from book by month year from library.

This is how each document looks like.
for book

```
{
    "_id" : "isbn-22553564",
    "title" : "Boerworse is baie Lekker",
    "genre" : "Sci-Fi"
}
```

for library

```
    "_id" : "postcode-10927886",
    "postcode" : "10927886",
    "dateLoaded" : "2020-08-12"
    "town" : "Wonderland"
}
```

for book_library which contains the id's of both book and library with link source and link destination as fields in this collection

```
{
    "_id" : "isbn-22553564_postcode-10927886",
    "lnkSrc" : "isbn-22553564",
    "lnkDst" : "postcode-10927886"
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get the genre and dateLoaded so I can count how many books for "Sci-fi" and "Documentary" where loaded per month per year in the form close to

count per genre for month and year combination

```
{
      genre: "Sci-Fi" 
      period: "08-2020" 
      count: 20
   }
   {
      genre: "Documentary" 
      period: "09-2020" 
      count: 2
   }
```

I tried using 2 $lookup with unwind as below

```
db.getCollection('book').aggregate([
                       { 
                           $lookup:{
                               localField: '_id',
                               from: 'book_library',
                               foreignField: '_id',
                               as: 'table1'
                               
                            }}, 
                            {
                                    $unwind: '$table1'
                            }, 
                            {
                                $lookup:{
                                   localField: 'lnkSrc',
                                   from: 'library',
                                   foreignField: '_id',
                                   as: 'table2'
                            }
                        }    
])
```

But on the resulting search I only receive an empty array on table2 even if I switch up which collection goes first

```
table2 : []
```

How do I make sure that the second table show results?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

On the first `$lookup` you are using the wrong field for `foreignField`. In your example, the `_id` field for the `books` collection looks like this: `isbn-22553564`. In your `book_library` collection, this corresponds to the `lnkSrc` field. So the first aggregation stage should look like this:

```
{ 
  $lookup: {
    localField: '_id',
    from: 'book_library',
    foreignField: 'lnkSrc',
    as: 'table1'
  }
}
```

At this point your documents will have the following form:

```
{
  "_id" : "isbn-22553564",
  "title" : "Boerworse is baie Lekker",
  "genre" : "Sci-Fi",
  "table1": [
    {
      "_id" : "isbn-22553564_postcode-10927886",
      "lnkSrc" : "isbn-22553564",
      "lnkDst" : "postcode-10927886"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `$unwind` stage, will create a document for each element in the `table1` array, resulting in documents like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "isbn-22553564",
  "title" : "Boerworse is baie Lekker",
  "genre" : "Sci-Fi",
  "table1": {
    "_id" : "isbn-22553564_postcode-10927886",
    "lnkSrc" : "isbn-22553564",
    "lnkDst" : "postcode-10927886"
  }
}
```

Note that now the `table1` field is an object instead of an array.

The final `$lookup` stage needs to use the `lnkDst` field from the `table1` document -- `lnkSrc` refers to the `_id` of the book document. Because `lnkDst` is nested in the `table1` document, the `$lookup` stage looks like this:

```
{ 
  $lookup: {
    localField: 'table1.lnkDst',
    from: 'library',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'table2'
  }
}
```

When this is all put together, the aggregation pipeline looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('book').aggregate([
{ 
  $lookup: {
    localField: '_id',
    from: 'book_library',
    foreignField: 'lnkSrc',
    as: 'table1'
  }
},
{ 
  $unwind: '$table1'
},
{ 
  $lookup: {
    localField: 'table1.lnkDst',
    from: 'library',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'table2'
  }
}])
```